# Can a primary key called twice in another table as foreign key using Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, foreign-keys

How can I use a primary key as a foreign key of another table's in two columns.

```
public class ResumeSharing
{
        [Key]
        public int ResumeSharingId { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("AppliedJobs")]
        public int AppliedJobId { get; set; }
        public virtual AppliedJob AppliedJobs { get; set; }
        public bool OwnCompany { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "RecruiterFrom")]
        public int RecruiterId { get; set; }
        public virtual Recruiter Recruiters { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "RecruiterTo")]
        public int RecruiterId { get; set; }
        public virtual Recruiter Recruiters { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("Companies")]
        public int CompanyId { get; set; }
        public virtual Company Companies { get; set; }

        public string SharedFiles { get; set; }
}
```

I want to call `RecruiterId` twice in this table. How can I do this?

Comment: What do you mean by *call* a primary key?? Do you mean **reference** ? As in store twice in a child table?

Answer (score 1):

you have to add navigation properties

```
public class ResumeSharing
    {
        [Key]
        public int ResumeSharingId { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("AppliedJob")]
        public int AppliedJobId { get; set; }
        public virtual AppliedJob AppliedJob { get; set; }
        public bool OwnCompany { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "RecruiterFrom")]
        public int RecruiterFromId { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey(nameof(RecruiterFromId))]
        [InverseProperty("RecruiterFroms")]
        public virtual Recruiter RecruiterFrom { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "RecruiterTo")]
        public int RecruiterToId { get; set; }
       [ForeignKey(nameof(RecruiterToId))]
        [InverseProperty("RecruiterTos")]
        public virtual Recruiter RecruiterTo { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("Company")]
        public int CompanyId { get; set; }
        public virtual Company Company { get; set; }

        public string SharedFiles { get; set; }
    }


public class Recruiter
{
[Key]
 public int Id { get; set; }

[InverseProperty(nameof(ResumeSharing.RecruiterFrom))]
public virtual ICollection<Recruiter> RecruiterFroms { get; set; }


[InverseProperty(nameof(ResumeSharing.RecruiterTo))]
public virtual ICollection<Recruiter> RecruiterTos { get; set; }
}
```